# The next weeks, the coming weeks or the upcoming weeks?

Tags: word-choice

I have a task  (for example - calculating costs of ... ) and I plan to complete it in some weeks (but I don't know exactly how much time is needed) and I have to report to my boss.
What are the correct preposition and adjective?

- The task will be completed in/during the next/coming/upcoming/following weeks.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I would say:

> The task will be completed in a few weeks

Comment: Hi @hubbledeepfield, that is another opportunity. I want to understand which adjectives are correct and which aren't.